# How to add Android plugins in build.gradle for Flutter Projects?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, plugins

In `android/app/build.gradle`, there is no "plugins {}" block. Instead, there are some "apply plugin":

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
```

Now, I want to add another Android plugin, how should I do that? I've tried writing a "plugins {}" block, but that does not work. I've also tried `apply plugin: 'my.plugin.name'`, but that also results in an error.

Is there a way that I can add custom Androids plugins into a Flutter Project?

Here is what I want: I need the google map SDK for Android in my project, which requires this plugin :`'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'`.

I know there is a flutter package on google map, but it does not support heat map, so I have to go native.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SOF! Please post your error log in both cases using https://pastebin.com or https://paste.ee

Answer (score 0):

The same way they're written. Write apply plugin:'PUT-YOUR-PLUGIN-HERE" and avoid putting 'id' before the plugins

Answer (score 0):

Recently flutter change Gradle structure. Now you can add your plugin inside **setting.gradle** file

```
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    plugins {
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" version "1.0.0" apply false
        **// Add your plugin here.**
    }
}

include ":app"

apply from: "${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```